# AngularJS with JqueryUI, dragover and ng-show issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I encountered a problem while working with AngularJS and JqueryUI, [here is a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3BQv7hUQEVsxbKhPweSe?p=preview).

```
angular.module("app").directive("draggable", function($timeout) {
  [...]
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.draggable({
      start: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.setDisplay(true);
        });
      },
      stop: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.setDisplay(false);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

angular.module("app").directive("dragover", function($timeout) {
  [...]
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.droppable({
      over: function(event, ui) {
        $timeout(scope.dragover);
      }
    });
  }
});

<div ng-app="app" id="container" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div id="counter">{{overedCounter}}</div>
  <div id="draggable" draggable></div>
  <div id="droppable" ng-show="display" dragover="overed"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the "dragover" event is not triggered when a draggable is over a droppable that is visible only during the drag. To make the event fired, you have to drag out of the window to create a scroll bar, then the event is fired.

I notice that the issue is caused by the fact that the droppable element is not "visible" for JqueryUI ([here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/droppable.js#L400)), so the event is not fired.

Do you know how i can "update" the element to set the new visibility ? Should I open an issue on the AngularJS project ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events to change the droppable visibility instead, the new defenition of draggable.directive.js goes as follows:

```
angular.module("app").directive("draggable", function($timeout){
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.mousedown( function(){
      element.data("mousedown", 1);
    });

   element.mousemove(function(){
       if(element.data("mousedown") == 1){
          scope.setDisplay(true); 
          scope.$digest();
       }
    });

    element.mouseup( function(){ 
      element.removeData("mousedown");
      scope.setDisplay(false); 
      scope.$digest(); 
    }); 

   element.draggable();
  }
});
```

Comment: Good workaround, thanks ! But the behaviour is not the same, here the droppable appears when the draggable is clicked, not when it is dragged.

Comment: I see, I've updated the solution to consider dragging behavior using mousemove too, should result in the expected behavior.